# Suppress Windows Integrated authentication and only anonymous authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I have an intranet, where the users "logs in" with AD. And here the Anonymous authentication works like a charm.

But, some of our users are not registered in AD, and when this is the issue, the users should be met with a login page that I design, not the "Windows Integrated authentication" login popup.

As I can understand it from Microsoft, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258063 "Windows Integrated authentication" will always apply if "Anonymous authentication" does not work. Is there any way to pypass this, and only offer the "Anonymous authentication", and if this fails, direct them to a webpage?